# transferring Action from 1 view controller to another

Tags: ios, swift, button

[image: is the MAIN VIEW containing the Container]i have a button(procceed) on the containerView of a viewcontroller."procceed" on being tapped needs to show a color change of another button placed on the main view of which the above former is a part.

[image: is the CONTAINER view having the button procceed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using NotificationCenter like so:

ContainerViewController.swift

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateButtonColor"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
```

MainViewController.swift

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.updateColor), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateButtonColor"), object: nil)


@objc func updateColor() {

    CartButton.tintColor = .green

}
```

Comment: actually i do'nt knwo why you people are getting confused. the button say chechkout in the mainVC's color needs to be changed on pressing the proceed button which is on containerVC. Please tell now.

Comment: This answer should be correct. You need to read his answer carefully. In container vc, where you write your code for proceed button, you have to post the notification and add the Observer in Main Vc. That will do your job. Else you have to use delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Delage method like below.

```
import UIKit

protocol containerVCDelegate: class {
       func changeBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor?)
}

class containerVC: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: containerVCDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func proceedClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.changeBackgroundColor(backgroundColor)
    }

}
```

Below codes should be there in your Main Vc

```
import UIKit


class mainVC: UIViewController, containerVCDelegate {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        containerVc.delegate = self
    }


    func changeBackgroundColor(_ color: UIColor?) {
        view.backgroundColor = color
    }

}
```

you can get the complete project here: https://github.com/jamesrochabrun/DelegateTutorialFinal
Refer [this](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef) link for more clarification on this concept written by **James Rochabrun**.